Telegraf cannot reach URL
I wrote a small telegraf.conf. When I put it in a docker compose it works. When I put it in my Kubernetes CLuster it does not.
The logs say: [inputs.http] Error in plugin: [url=https://dwd.api.proxy.bund.dev/v30/stationOverviewExtended?stationIds=10838,10840]: Get "https://dwd.api.proxy.bund.dev/v30/stationOverviewExtended?stationIds=10838,10840": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
I tried with http://google.de as altenrative url (for debugging) with the same result.
[agent]
  interval = "10s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
  debug = false
  quiet = false
  logfile = ""
  hostname = ""
  omit_hostname = false

[[inputs.http]]
  ## URL zur GET-Anfrage
  urls = [
    "https://dwd.api.proxy.bund.dev/v30/stationOverviewExtended?stationIds=10838,10840"
  ]
  method = "GET"
  interval = "10s"
  response_timeout = "5s"
  data_format = "json"

[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  ## InfluxDB 2.0 URL
  urls = ["http://influxdb-nfluxdb2.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:8086"]
  organization = "influxdata"
  bucket = "default"
  token = "securetoken"

I expected the config to work both with docker compose and within Kubernetes(K3s).

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.
